# Trigger jQuery's hover() over anchor to show drop-downs within containing LIs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, navigation, hover

I have a horizontal nav bar that is an unordered list with anchor tags. It currently uses jQuery's hover (mouseover and mouseout) to show drop-down navigation in each LI.

How can I make it so instead of triggering the drop-down when hoving over the LI it will be triggered when mousing over the anchor tag? When I changed it to the anchor the drop-down always disappears when mousing down over top of it, but it works fine when I set the LI to as the target for the hover() (I guess because all of the drop-down code is wrapped in the LI so the cursor is still hovering over the LI).

I need to set it up this way due to the design, so there isn't any way to change it. I need the hover() to be triggered just from the anchor and not the LI.

Comment: can you host the code on jsfiddle. Cant imagine the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could change the class of the LI by the hover code for the anchor. Change it back when you move off the LI.

Answer (score 1):

The problem you're having, if I understand correctly, is that the dropdown closes before you get your mouse to it. This is probably because there's a gap between the anchor tag and the dropdown menu.

So how about, you change the opener to the a-tag, but then you add a little timer that keeps the dropdown list opened for one or more seconds even if you mouse out? Such an addition is nice to have later anyway, gets irritating if you accidentally mouse out of a navbar and have to go back because it closed.

Edit: Also, yes, JSFiddle it.

Answer (score 1):

Try putting a span tag inside your anchor:

```
<a href='#'><span>test</span></a>

a span {
    display: block;
}
```